# Join on previous date if same date is not available?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2jf3.jpg)

I would like to join the balance table to the orders on each UID and stock_name and dates. The date should join on the same or previous available date.

Here is my initial code but it would return null if date is not available during the order date.

```
Select a.date, 
    a.stock_name, 
    a.UID, 
    a.Sale,
    b.avg_price, 
    a.Sale-b.avg_price as Gain
from orders as a
left join balance as b on a.UID = b.UID and a.stock_name = b.stock_name and a.date = b.date
order by a.date desc
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I suggest a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). `a` is not a good alias for an object called `orders`; there is no `a` in it.

Comment: Why you don't exclude "Date" from join conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ...) for this. Try:

```
outer apply (
    select top 1 *
    from balance as b
    where a.UID = b.UID
    and a.stock_name = b.stock_name
    and a.date >= b.date
    order by b.date desc
) b
```

This will select the closest balance date at or earlier than the order date. If the resulting b is null, there is no balance record. OUTER APPLY is like a LEFT OUTER JOIN, while CROSS APPLY is like a regular INNER JOIN. Which you use depends on how you prefer to handle the no-match condition.